# ffprobe/ffmpg silence detection command

Tags: json, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm working on a stream silence detection.
It's working on the following command in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i http://mystream.com/stream -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2> log.txt
```

I would like to get a json output of the logfile.
There is a json option in 'ffprobe' but `silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=0.5` is'nt working.

Help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ffprobe is meant to probe container-level or stream-level metadata. `silencedetect` is a filter which analyses the content of decoded audio streams; its output isn't controlled by the choice of writer.

What you could do, since silencedetect also logs its result to metadata tags, is output just that data to a file.

```
ffmpeg -i http://mystream.com/stream -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=0.5,ametadata=print:file=log.txt -f null -
```

Output

```
frame:281  pts:323712  pts_time:6.744  
lavfi.silence_start=6.244
frame:285  pts:328320  pts_time:6.84   
lavfi.silence_end=6.84
lavfi.silence_duration=0.596
frame:413  pts:475776  pts_time:9.912  
lavfi.silence_start=9.412
frame:1224 pts:1410048 pts_time:29.376 
lavfi.silence_end=29.376
lavfi.silence_duration=19.964
```