# FFmpeg cut video end with no sound

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to remove the end of a video that has no sound?

: = Has Sound
. = No Sound

00:00 [::::::::::::::::::::::::::::........] 01:24
____________________^^^^^ Cut this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note time when sound ends, such as 00:01:23, then use:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c copy -t 00:01:23 output
```

- You can use seconds if you prefer, such as `-t 83`.
- Exact time is not guaranteed with [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c copy`). If exactness is a requirement then remove `-c copy`.
- If you want to automate it (you didn't specify) then integrate the [silencedetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect) filter. It will output timestamps of detected silence, then use the supplied timestamps to create your `ffmpeg` command. See [ffprobe/ffmpeg silence detection command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807682/) for an example showing how to get the timestamps.